# Why do I get ClassCastException when trying to read objects from my file?

Tags: arrays, classcastexception, serializable

I get a runtime-error that says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: lab07.Loan cannot be cast to [Llab07.Loan;
    at lab07.TestLoanClass.main(TestLoanClass.java:27).

The fault might be in the serializable class Loan, but have a look at this one first. Because it all works just fine if I avoid using arrays. I am using the Eclipse IDE.

```
public class TestLoanClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    Loan[] loan = new Loan[5];

    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("Exercise19_06.dat"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        loan[i] = new Loan(1.5 * i,i * 2,10000 * i);
        output.writeObject(loan[i]);
    }
    output.close();

    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            "Exercise19_06.dat"));


    //Conversion below is perfectly legal to type, but I get an error when 
    //I run the program. Appearently it has something with Object being 
    //cast to a Loan. Shouldn't the error show up while writing the code?

      Loan[] loanRead = (Loan[]) (input.readObject());

    //However, it work's just fine if I avoid using an array

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

        System.out
                .printf("The loan was created on %s\n"
                        + "The monthly payment is %.2f\nThe total payment is %.2f\n",
                        loanRead[j].getLoanDate().toString(),
                        loanRead[j].getMonthlyPayment(),
                        loanRead[j].getTotalPayment());
    }

    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete  `Loan[] loanRead = (Loan[]) (input.readObject());` and put  `loan[j] = (Loan) (input.readObject());` in a second for loop.

And of course change all occurences of `loanRead[j]` in a for loop with `loan[j]`.

Comment: That worked perfectly fine sir :) Thanks. I guess my error was that I was trying to read just one object into the whole general array or something in that vein. Must remember to read one object at a time.